# scrolling a background image in pyglet

Tags: python, game-development, pyglet

I am new to pyglet.I am trying to a have a seamlessly scrolling background. 
I have tried everything i could find on stack and google. I turned vsync off because it improved the performance in my computer. I have even used batch to draw on my screen. Used the preload function to load my image and in my Game class convert it to sprite.
What else can i do to make my background scroll smoothly?
Thanks in Advance.

This is my code:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE)

pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
TITLE = 'Bunny'

def preload_image(img):
    pyglet.resource.path = ['../res']
    pyglet.resource.reindex()
    image = pyglet.resource.image(img)
    return image    

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(main, self).__init__(800, 600, fullscreen=False, vsync=False)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.sprites = {}
        self.batches = {}
        self.subgroups = {}

        self._handles = {}

        self.batches['main'] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.subgroups['base'] = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(0)

        self.background = preload_image('mountains.png')
        self.background.width = WIDTH
        self.background.height = HEIGHT
        self.background_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.background, 0, 0, batch=self.batches['main'])
        self.background_sprite1 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.background, WIDTH, 0, batch=self.batches['main'])
        self.speed = 30
        self.frame_rate = 60.0
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.run, 1.0 / self.frame_rate)
        pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(self.frame_rate)

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        for batch_name, batch in self.batches.items():
            batch.draw()

        for sprite_name, sprite in self.sprites.items():
            sprite._draw()

        self.flip() 

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()
            dt = 1/pyglet.clock.get_fps_limit()
            print(1/dt)
            self.background_sprite.x -= self.speed * dt
            self.background_sprite1.x -= self.speed * dt
            if self.background_sprite1.x < -WIDTH: self.background_sprite1.x = WIDTH
            if self.background_sprite.x < -WIDTH: self.background_sprite.x = WIDTH

            event = self.dispatch_events()


x = main()
x.run()
```

[As you can see in the image, there is a small black line in between the two background scrolling images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qONrA.png)

Comment: The main problem here is the equation `self.background_sprite.x -= self.speed * dt` gives a float number. And the way the position gets automatically rounded up or down, will generate the black line. The easiest solution would be to use one's image as a reference point for the other. doing `sprite2.x = sprite1.x + sprite1.width` or something similar :) Sorry for a slow answer, I've been meaning to get back to you for a few days now.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make changes to my run function like this:

Comment: `background_pos = self.background_sprite.x` and 
        `background_pos1 = self.background_sprite1.x`
and then assigned them to:
`background_pos -= self.speed * dt` and
`background_pos1 -= self.speed * dt`

Comment: lastly cast them to integer values `self.background_sprite.x = int(background_pos)`, `self.background_sprite1.x = int(background_pos1)`